# How to install/enable swagger-edior with connexion?

Tags: swagger, connexion

After installing and doing a basic setup of flask and connexion, I can visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/myapi/ui and browse myapi.

How can I install/access the other swagger tools, for. ex. the editor?

Answer (score 0):

By further reading I found out, that in difference to to the swagger-ui, you normally don't want the editor or code generator inside your project. You can see it as tools that stands for its own. To get it run, in my case on windows, I first installed [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). After that you can install the tools with `npm`.

```
> git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor.git
> cd swagger-editor
> npm run ...
```